# A short way to execute a dynamic SQL string

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I have a table, and a column with a query in it. And I want to update this table, converting the value to the result of it's execution.

This is a well known example of such table actually: `all_tab_partitions`. It has a column `HIGH_VALUE` with values like:

```
TO_DATE('2016-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS').
```

One could extract the date via *substring*s or *regexps*, but may be Oracle-guys think of exactly converting it via dynamic execution.

Comment: Not entirely sure what it is you are trying to achieve. You seem to be suggesting that 'TO_DATE('2016-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')' is a query when it clearly isn't and you can't just update the all_tab_partitions VIEW. You will use the ALTER TABLE command to modify partitions - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2087440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a rather straight way to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PARSE_(STR VARCHAR2)
RETURN DATE
IS
    c NUMBER;
    r INTEGER;
    val DATE;
BEGIN
    c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, 'SELECT ' || str || ' FROM DUAL', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(c, 1, val);

    r := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
    LOOP
        IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(c) > 0 THEN
            -- get column values of the row
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(c, 1, val);
        ELSE
            EXIT;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);

    RETURN val;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF DBMS_SQL.IS_OPEN(c) THEN
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
/

SELECT PARSE_('TO_DATE(''2016-01-01 00:00:00'', ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'')') AS d FROM DUAL;
-- 01.01.2016
```

And if you want to use it with an `all_tab_partitions.HIGH_VALUE`, the `HIGH_VALUE` field has to be converted previously. I've made this in 2 step:

1. create temp table with `TO_LOB(HIGH_VALUE) AS HV` field
2. select from this temp table with `PARSE_(TO_CHAR(HV))`.

Comment: I would just note that this is rife for an SQL injection attack

Comment: Definitely it is. I've mentioned the system oracle table as a main target for this query. I would not use it for anything else)